# Asynchronous complete condition with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a page with three dropzones which each call a function to update an image on the site once they're complete. The problem is that if three files are being uploaded at the same time, the function does not fire until the last of the three has finished uploading. Is there a way to fire off an iteration of the function every single time a file is uploaded?

Javascript:

```
var updatePreview = function(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
            var pageSize = '',
                source_preview = '',
                source_preview_background = '';

            if ($(data).find('#file_0' + page + ' .ledger_preview').length) {
                //If paper is ledger-size
                source_preview = $(data).find('#file_0' + page + ' .ledger_preview'),
                source_preview_background = source_preview.css('background-image');
                $('#file_0' + page + ' .ledger_preview').css('background-image', source_preview_background);
            }
            else {
                //If paper is letter-size
                source_preview = $(data).find('#file_0' + page + ' .letter_preview'),
                source_preview_background = source_preview.css('background-image');
                $('#file_0' + page + ' .letter_preview').css('background-image', source_preview_background);
            }
       }
    });
};

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var dzOne = new Dropzone('#file-one', {
    url: 'submit.php',
    paramName: 'file_01',
    method: 'POST',
    init: function() {
        this.on('complete', function() {
            updatePreview('1');
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
    }
});

var dzTwo = new Dropzone('#file-two', {
    url: 'submit.php',
    paramName: 'file_02',
    method: 'POST',
    init: function() {
        this.on('complete', function() {
            updatePreview('2');
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
    }
});

var dzThree = new Dropzone('#file-three', {
    url: 'submit.php',
    paramName: 'file_03',
    method: 'POST',
    init: function() {
        this.on('complete', function() {
            updatePreview('3');
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        done();
    }
});
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? Otherwise do you know about promises?

Comment: Not really - I read a tiny bit about them but I'm not entirely sure how to apply them to this situation...

Comment: Well JQuery ajax is a kind of a promise, when it gets the data it resolves and calls the success function. What you are looking for is the progress callback. Though if you can you should simply start 3 ajax calls and seperate the img calls, that is much more clean-

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to what you're referring to when you say progress callback - In dropzone, or $.ajax?

Comment: In promises in general, but as I said multiple requests make more sense in this context unless, your js can diffrentiate when the one image has finished

Comment: try using the on `success` instead of on `complete`